# Does residue depends on branch?

Tags: laurent-series, branch-cuts

I'm a physics student and learning complex analysis (to do definite integrals)
I think I lack knowledge in complex analysis because I cannot follow the logic in the following example.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_6_.E2.80.93_logarithms_and_the_residue_at_infinity
In this example 6 about contour integral in Wikipedia, I have a question. I cannot see why we should set
$-\pi<\mathrm{arg}(z)<\pi$ and $0<\mathrm{arg}(3-z)<2\pi$
I think it would be more natural to set
$-\pi<\mathrm{arg}(z)<\pi$ and $-\pi <\mathrm{arg}(3-z)<\pi$
It doesn't change the branch cut, just branch themselves (maybe).
But if I change them, I cannot get answer. Answer becomes imaginary.
I think there are 2 possibilities.
1. Residue also changes when I change the branch so the final answer remains same.
2. I cannot set the branches like that.
But I cannot sure what is right, and why.

Can someone explain me where I did wrong?

Comment: Let $g(z) = \frac{ \log(1+z)}{z}$. What are the different branches analytic on $|z| < 1$ and what is $\text{Res}(g(z),0)$ ? In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_6_.E2.80.93_logarithms_and_the_residue_at_infinity) example all we care about is having a branch analytic on  $\mathbb{C} \setminus [0,3]$ so that $ \int_3^0+\int_0^{3 e^{2i \pi}}f(z)dz=\int_{|z| = 6} f(z)dz =\int_{|s| = 1/6} f(1/s)\frac{ds}{s^2} $

Comment: I'm sorry I still didn't get it, so why my branches are not working? Are they not analytic on C \ [0,3] ?